# How to update pidgin-sipe

Tags: upgrade

Does anyone know how to update pidgin-sipe using package manager? The current version is `1.17.3-1.` They changed something on the Microsoft Office 365 Lync and pidgin now fails with:

```
Authentication method not supported.
```

It was working until not too long ago. The only thing left is to try and update sipe to see if it works.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this issue installing sipe from source

First you need to install development packages as described [here](http://sipe.sourceforge.net/install/)
Edit : added 2 libs that are not on the sipe instructions

```
sudo apt-get install autotools-dev pkg-config libglib2.0-dev \
libgtk2.0-dev libpurple-dev libtool intltool comerr-dev \
libnss3-dev libxml2-dev
```

Download sipe 1.20 from sipe page project to /tmp and uncompress

```
mkdir -p /tmp/sipe
cd /tmp/sipe
wget -O pidgin-sipe-1.20.0.tar.gz http://sourceforge.net/projects/sipe/files/sipe/pidgin-sipe-1.20.0/pidgin-sipe-1.20.0.tar.gz/download
tar -zxvf pidgin-sipe-1.20.0.tar.gz
cd /tmp/sipe/pidgin-sipe-1.20.0/
```

Compile and install, following the simple instructions from [here](http://daviwa.blogspot.cl/2015/09/pidgin-2109-how-to-install-pidgin-sipe.html)

```
cd /tmp/sipe/pidgin-sipe-1.20.0/
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
```

**The config on Pidgin that work for me**

"Basic" Tab

```
Username : username@domain.com
Login : domain.com\username
```

"Advanced" Tab

```
Connection Type: Auto
User Agent: UCCAPI/15.0.4420.1017 OC/15.0.4420.1017 (Microsoft Lync)
Authentication Scheme: TLS-DSK

* Everything else empty or unchecked
```

Comment: Not so easy because besides the packages you listed there were a few others missing (libxml2, openssl-dev, etc). After lots of pain (partly due to the fact that those particular packages don't show up in the repository exactly as reported by configure fail. I kinda got passed the install but now I get a connection error (reason: 7 description. You have been rejected by the server at https://portal.microsoftonline.com/download/lync.aspx). I still say Micro$loth is doing this on purpose to force people to use their stupid OS in which case I would be very p**sed.

Thanks

Comment: i added the 2 necessary missing libs to the instructions, both are in the repos, so maybe if you recompile with those, and use the settings described it may work. I recreate the complete process in a fresh install (vm) and it worked perfectly with those 2 additions.

Comment: Yes I actually got it working by using the missing packages using dpkg before with the User Agent (UCC.... ) and Login: (blank). It would be nice if someone added the binary updates as Micro$loth breaks things.